# iOS google places API - compile error - use of undeclared identifier GMSAutocompleteViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-places-api, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have installed GoogleMaps SDK using CocoaPods.
For some screen I need to use Google Places API
Here is the code 

`GMSAutocompleteViewController *acController = [[GMSAutocompleteViewController alloc] init];
acController.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:acController animated:YES completion:nil];`

Which  I have got from https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete

The error - use of undeclared identifier 'GMSAutocompleteViewController'

Comment: Maybe you forgot to import the actual framework?

Comment: Thanks, I did, it seems that I didn't update framework. Check the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you added `#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>` to the file?

The other possibility is that you have an older version of the GoogleMaps pod (`GMSAutocompleteViewController` was added in version 1.11). To fix this, just run

`pod update`

in the project directory.

Comment: I have added import GoogleMaps. I have checked in GoogleMaps framework headers and found that GMSAutocompleteViewController is not available.  Updated the pod and now I got it. Thanks.

Comment: When I update to 1.11 I am getting this Pod issue: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9030

Any suggestion?

Comment: I'd suggest not checking binary artifacts into source control at all. It's not really necessary.