# I'm trying to add to the project pod api to autocompletion cities, pod 'GoogleMaps'. But I do not have all the files in the folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, cocoapods

I'm trying to add to the project pod api to autocompletion cities, pod 'GoogleMaps'. But I do not have all the files in the folder.

I recently did a project and added in the same way API, and everything worked perfectly. Now xcode tells me that the file is missing. I really can not understand what the problem is and why cocoapods adds all the files in the project.
Is attached screenshots, should look like folder headers, and how it actually look like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnCa4.png)

files that are missing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6O4e.png)

file that not added cocoaPods

Maybe somebody knows what's the problem?
I would be very grateful ...

Comment: can it be a problem of xcode indexing? a good old xcode restart?

Comment: No, unfortunately not helped restart...(

Answer (score 0):

It is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34870355/5832311) to make sure that you have added `import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>` to the file.

> The other possibility is that you have an older version of the GoogleMaps pod ([`GMSAutocompleteViewController`](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/reference/interface_g_m_s_autocomplete_view_controller) was added in version 1.11). To fix this, just run `pod update` in the project directory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried to update pod, but constantly come to the terminal this message: CocoaPods 1.2.0.beta.1 is available.
To update use: `sudo gem install cocoapods --pre`
[!] This is a test version we'd love you to try.

For more information, see https://blog.cocoapods.org and the CHANGELOG for this version at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.2.0.beta.1. After all, my problem is not solved.